# How to assign to element in array in R

Tags: arrays, r, expression, assign

**In a function**, I want to assign some value to some other environment (not the parent environment). e.g.,

```
assign('a', 30, envir = someOtherEnvironment)
```

Then `a` in `someOtherEnvironment` becomes 30.

But if it is an array `b`, e.g. in `someOtherEnvironment` there is an array `b <-array(1:6, dim = c(2,3))` Then if I do this,

```
assign('b[1,2]', 30, envir = someOtherEnvironment)
```

That doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Using `assign` is often not necessary.

Comment: @Heroka I'm in a function, and I need to assign the value into another environment.

Comment: `someOtherEnvironment$b[1,2] <- 30` seems to work, as does: `someOtherEnvironment[["b"]][1,2] <- 30`